# JPA toplink cascade persist with javadb has null foreign key

Tags: jpa, javadb, toplink

I am getting an exception when trying to persist a one-to-many relationship.  I can see that the problem occurs because the parent's (policy) auto generated id is not being used when inserting the child (link).

SQL commands:

```
CREATE TABLE POLICIES
(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  CURRENTLINKID INTEGER,
);

CREATE TABLE LINKS
(
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  ORDINAL INTEGER NOT NULL,
  LINK VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  POLICYID INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE POLICIES
ADD FOREIGN KEY(CURRENTLINKID) 
REFERENCES LINKS(ID);

ALTER TABLE LINKS
ADD FOREIGN KEY(POLICYID) 
REFERENCES POLICIES(ID);
```

Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POLICIES", catalog = "", schema = "")
public class PolicyEntity
{
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "_policy")
    private Collection<LinkEntity> _linkEntityCollection;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "LINKS", catalog = "", schema = "")
public class LinkEntity
{
    ...
    @JoinColumn(name = "POLICYID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    private PolicyEntity _policy;
    ...
}
```

Create entities and persist:

```
LinkEntity link = new LinkEntity();
link.setLink("link");
link.setOrdinal(1);

List<LinkEntity> links = new ArrayList<LinkEntity>();
links.add(link);

PolicyEntity policy = new PolicyEntity();
policy.setLinks(links);

EntityManager entityManager = _emf.createEntityManager();

// Begin transaction
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

// persist
entityManager.persist(policy);

// Commit the transaction
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

// Close this EntityManager
entityManager.close();
```

Exception:

> javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [TOPLINK-4002] (Oracle
>   TopLink Essentials - 2006.8 (Build 060830)):
>   oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column
>   'POLICYID'  cannot accept a NULL value.Error Code: 20000 Call:INSERT
>   INTO LINKS (LINK, ORDINAL, POLICYID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)     bind => [link,
>   1, **null**]
>   Query:InsertObjectQuery(xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.datalayer.entities.LinkEntity@1bb813b)

---

Call:INSERT INTO LINKS (LINK, ORDINAL, POLICYID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [link, 1, null]  <--- how to set the auto generated policy id here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED per Chris's comment.

I realized I needed to actually set the policy in the link entity.  Now the links are inserted without exception.

```
PolicyEntity policy = new PolicyEntity();
LinkEntity link = new LinkEntity();
link.setLink("link");
link.setOrdinal(1);
link.setPolicy(policy) // set policy so it wasn't null

List<LinkEntity> links = new ArrayList<LinkEntity>();
links.add(link);

policy.setLinks(links);
```

Comment: The mapping change isn't needed, only setting calling the link.setPolicy(policy) is required to populate the foreign key field in the link table.